# What is the correct encoding for filesystem path strings?

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring, filesystems

When I take a path in an `NSString` and turn around and use it in a C API, for example:

```
CGDataProviderRef CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(const char *filename );
```

What is the correct encoding for the path when flattening to a `char*`? UTF8? (ASCII??)

I feel like this should be either obvious, or obviously documented, but I'm having trouble thinking and/or finding the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`-[NSString fileSystemRepresentation]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-fileSystemRepresentation).

Comment: Bingo. I knew there was something like this out there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

an example that worked for me using the above answer

```
NSString *path =@"/Users/ethansanford/Desktop/mutable string logic/mutable string logic/long-arrow-right.png" ;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(path.fileSystemRepresentation);
imageRef2 =CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by providing some explanation.